# Removing special characters in dynamic schema

Tags: java, csv, special-characters, csvhelper, dynamic-schema

Requirement:
Source file:

```
abc,''test,data'',valid
xyz,''sample,data'',invalid
```

the data in source file we need to read dynamically. We are reading entire data in one string column. One of the value and file delimiter have comma separator. I have to load data in target table as follows with out double quotes
Target table :

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
abc|test,data|valid
xyz|sample,data|invalid
```

Comment: Is `test,data` really bracketed at the beginning and end by **two single quote characters `''`** or is it actually bracketed by **one double-quote character `"`**?

Comment: Also, you have tagged this [tag:java] and [tag:csvhelper] but [CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csvhelper/info) is *a **.NET** library that allows for easy reading and writing of comma-separated values (CSV) files.* so can't be used with Java.  Are you actually using [this library](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or something else?